# Move a CGPoint dependant on device orientation

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I have a CGPoint which is set in the iPhones portrait orientation. How can I translate this point when the iPhone moves to landscape, so that it maintains its location proportionally to the edges of the screen? And back again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your View Controller make your CGPoint an instance variable and overwrite this method (check it in the UIViewController documentation):

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

You will need some code to calculate the new point to make it proportional how you want. Allowing for the status bar, I think this is what you need (presuming my maths is okay):

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if ( (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) ) {
        myPoint = CGPointMake(320/460*myPoint.x, 460/320*myPoint.y);
    }
    else {
        myPoint = CGPointMake(460/320*myPoint.x, 320/460*myPoint.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keith, I can't help but think that this should work, I see what you are getting at with the maths, but it doesn't. The point is plotted off the screen on rotation.

Comment: Hi Keith, it was me, checking for wrong orientation. Your code works, I have marked your answer as correct - cheers, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this helper method:

```
- (CGPoint)adjustTouch:(CGPoint)aTouch forOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)aOrientation; {

  CGPoint touchLocation = CGPointZero;

  switch (aOrientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
      touchLocation = aTouch;
      break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
      touchLocation.x = aTouch.x;
      touchLocation.y = 480 - aTouch.y;
      break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
      touchLocation.x = aTouch.y;
      touchLocation.y = aTouch.x;
      break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
      touchLocation.x = 480 - aTouch.y;
      touchLocation.y = 320 - aTouch.x;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return touchLocation;
}
```

You may have to tweak the values in each case for what you want, as I'm not quite sure what you mean by "proportionally to the edges of the screen", but this should help you figure it out. Hope that Helps!